# Center children if they don't fit the parent

Tags: html, css

So my problem is that the parent has some width and if the screen cant fit everything the children (floated left) go one under the other (looks awesome as well) so I want them when they go one under the other to be centered in the parent.

Here is my code. I tried `inline-block` and it didn't help and so on

```
.mainpage-articles {
    float:left;
    width: 60%;
}

.mainpage-article {
    width: calc(800px + 8%);
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

}

.mainpage-article .thumbnail {
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    width: 400px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 2%;
    float: left;
}

.mainpage-article .thumbnail img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.mainpage-article .article {
    height: 200px;
    width: 400px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 2%;
    float: left;
}

.mainpage-article .article h1 {
    height: 60px;
}

.mainpage-article .article p {
    height: 120px;
}
```

Comment: You should be able to do this using `display: inline-block` instead of `float` on the nested elements, then declaring `text-align: center` to the parent element.

Comment: Please share if you've tried something. Please try to solve before asking

Comment: I tried I didn't want to share code because it's a lot but I edited and shared it. (not full tho... didn't let me share full code).

Comment: Provide your HTML markup too.

Comment: Take a look at this Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/srj1p8zL/ @NFSpeedy and share your thoughts.

Comment: @giovannipds kind of resembles a pokemon that cat

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError lol, it' a random img, have no idea what has shown over there, kk

Comment: @NFSpeedy you're probably wanting to learn media queries, to respond to the user's screen. Aren't you?

Comment: trying to avoid the media queries... seems too easy with them... So far noone has my idea... :D press F12 and play with the screen and when they go one below the other THAN you have to have the center too.

Comment: @NFSpeedy you're getting it wrong, there's no reason to avoid media queries if you ARE wanting to respond to the user's screen. Take a look at my updated answer.

Comment: media query will be required for text-align, flex, wrap  and min-width can set break points instead float: example https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/yzRypx

Answer (score 0):

You're probably wanting to learn media queries, to respond to the user's screen. Am I right? If it's that, take a look here: https://codepen.io/giovannipds/pen/BwqyLW

This is what you want to learn:

```
@media (max-width: 1500px) {
  .mainpage-articles {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

This code align text things to the center when the user window's is at max 1500px, above that it doesn't. There are many ways to apply media queries. I recommend you to **[watch this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2KL-z9A56SQ)** to learn it a little better.

Full code of the example above:

```
<style>
  .mainpage-articles {
    background-color: #eee;
    float: left;
    width: 60%;
  }
  .mainpage-article {
    background-color: cyan;
    width: calc(800px + 8%);
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
  .mainpage-article .thumbnail {
    background-color: yellow;
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    width: 400px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 2%;
    float: left;
  }
  .mainpage-article .thumbnail img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .mainpage-article .article {
    background-color: #ccc;
    height: 200px;
    width: 400px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 2%;
    float: left;
  }
  .mainpage-article .article h1 {
    height: 60px;
  }
  .mainpage-article .article p {
    height: 120px;
  }
  @media (max-width: 1500px) {
    .mainpage-articles {
      text-align: center;
    }
  }
</style>
<div class="mainpage-articles">
  <div class="mainpage-article">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="//lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="article">
      <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
      <p>Dolor sit amet.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

There's an example [here](https://codepen.io/giovannipds/pen/WZabrE) with [Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/) too:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style>
  .parent {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  .smth-else {
    background-color: cyan;
  }
  .children {
    margin: 75px !important;
  }
  .children [class^=col-] {
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
</style>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="parent col">
      <div class="children row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          Children col 1
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          Children col 2
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="smth-else col">
      Smth else
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Your code is not so pretty, you should adapt them to use media queries better.

Comment: YES! That's the idea but I'm not allowed to use Bootstrap or any other external library.